# Sap ui5 and xsjs

Tags: sapui5

I have created an SAP UI5 app in Web IDE and also a XSJS app using HANA web based tools. But I am unable to call the xsjs service directly from my Web IDE application using ajax call giving the full URL.

If anyone can give an idea it would be great.

Comment: I think you need to look at the direction of CloundConnector and setting up the so called "destinations" to allow webide making request to services.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a HTTP destination that includes the xsjs URL and the information of authorized database user from SAP Cloud Platform Connectivity section. Then you'll add that destination to your neo-app.json file like below, to be able to call it using "/customPathToUse". It's done.

```
{
  "path": "/customPathToUse",
  "target": {
    "type": "destination",
    "name": "NameOfTheDestination"
  },
  "description": "XS Destination"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Huseyin for the response.is xsjs configuration similar to xsodata? can you share a screenshot for the same.

Comment: No it's quite different. You can read this one https://blogs.sap.com/2016/09/20/creating-a-simple-proxy-using-xs-http-destinations-and-xsjs/.